# TextView's getLineSpacingExtra C#/mono equivalent

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

I am trying to calculate a view's visibility according to [this](http://www.accella.net/multi-column-text-displays-in-android/) case study, and to convert it to monodroid specific (using xamarin framework).
However I didn't find an equivalent for Java's `getLineSpacingExtra()` method (from TextView).
The problem that's being addressed is calculating the visible content on a magazine like app that builds column text views dynamically

Comment: It could be that you're targeting too low an API for that method; it was introduced in 4.1.

Comment: @user1132457 Makes sense, it is targeted on 2.3 thanks! if you have any ideas regarding text measurement too....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Xamarin.Android API](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aAndroid.Widget.TextView.LineSpacingExtra) there is a `LineSpacingExtra` property for the `TextView`.

With that being said I am unable to access the property programmatically.  I do, however, see it as a property when looking at something like an `Android.Widget.EditText` in the axml designer (see screenshot).

[image: lineSpacingExtra property shown in designer]

Comment: I was aware of that, also been trying to access it programmatically with no luck.. I think I need it in order for me to calculate how much text fits to a column for a magaizne-like app

Comment: You might want to update your question to include that information, and more on what problem you're trying to solve.  Maybe someone can offer an alternative!